# .jar não encontra o caminho dos relatórios ireport

Tags: java, exceção, netbeans, ireport

Boa tarde Senhores! 
Estou com um problema e nenhum dos outros posts conseguiu me ajudar... 
Estava verificando meu TCC e acabei de me deparar com o seguinte problema: O meu executável .JAR não consegue identificar a pasta onde estão os relatórios criados pelo iReport versão 5.6.0. 
No meu projeto, possuo uma pasta br.integrado.reports onde eu guardo todos os meus .jasper além de já ter importado as bibliotecas do iReport para o projeto. 
Esse é meu código para "impressão" do relatório:

```
public class RelatorioService {

private static final String FOLDER = "/br/integrado/reports";

public void gerarRelatorio(HashMap parametros, String nomeRelatorioJasper) throws JRException {

    String caminhoRelatorio = this.getClass().getResource(FOLDER).getPath();
    String caminhoArquivosJasper = caminhoRelatorio + File.separator + nomeRelatorioJasper + ".jasper";

    JasperReport relatorioJasper = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(caminhoArquivosJasper);

    JasperPrint impressoraJasper = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioJasper, parametros, ConexaoJDBC.getConexao());

    JasperViewer jrv = new JasperViewer(impressoraJasper, false);
    jrv.setVisible(true);
    jrv.toFront();
}
```

}

No netbeans funciona perfeitamente, porém no .jar ele me gera a seguinte exception pelo CMD:

```
nov 25, 2018 2:04:00 PM br.integrado.view.RelListagemClienteView jButton1ActionPerformed
```

GRAVE: null
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\willz\Documents\GitHub\TCC\StoreSoft\dist\StoreSoft.jar!\br\integrado\reports\ListagemClientesReport.jasper
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:114)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:103)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(JRLoader.java:94)
        at br.integrado.reports.RelatorioService.gerarRelatorio(RelatorioService.java:33)
        at br.integrado.view.RelListagemClienteView.imprimirRelatorio(RelListagemClienteView.java:269)
        at br.integrado.view.RelListagemClienteView.jButton1ActionPerformed(RelListagemClienteView.java:197)
        at br.integrado.view.RelListagemClienteView.access$300(RelListagemClienteView.java:24)
        at br.integrado.view.RelListagemClienteView$4.actionPerformed(RelListagemClienteView.java:136)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\willz\Documents\GitHub\TCC\StoreSoft\dist\StoreSoft.jar!\br\integrado\reports\ListagemClientesReport.jasper

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Experimente `String caminhoRelatorio = RelatorioService.class.getResourceAsStream(FOLDER)`. Por gentileza, avise se funcionar.

Comment: Bom dia! Segui suas intruções e no netbeans funciona perfeitamente, infelizmente no executável ainda continua com erro de NullPointer. Segue a print do código: http://prntscr.com/ln5gyh

Comment: Esse é o erro gerado no cmd junto ao caminho do arquivo: http://prntscr.com/ln5hmi

Comment: E esse é o diretório do meu dist: http://prntscr.com/ln5i20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido:

```
public void gerarRelatorio(HashMap parametros, String nomeRelatorioJasper) {
    try {
        JasperPrint relatorio = null;
        JasperReport jasperReport = null;
        InputStream jasperFile = Thread.currentThread().getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/integrado/reports/" + nomeRelatorioJasper + ".jasper");
        jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperFile);
        relatorio = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametros, ConexaoJDBC.getConexao());
        JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(relatorio, false);
        viewer.setTitle("Relatório");
        viewer.setVisible(true);
        viewer.toFront();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```